# Form is too zoomed in on 2k and 4k displayes

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, sass

I am new at web development so bear with me, please.

I built a simple form for a friend using react and bootstrap. It looked great on my work monitor which is 1080p but when I look at it at home on my 4k display, it looks way too zoomed in. I can't figure out how to make it look the same on 2k and 4k display(it looks the same on my MacBook pro 2k display)

Below is what I want it to look like on all displays.
[image]

And here is what it looks like on my 2k and 4k displayes
[image]

Here's the index.css file from my react app.

```
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.container {
   display: flex;
  flex-flow: column nowrap;
  height: 100%;
  
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  display: flex;
  font-weight: 400;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  background: #12c2e9;  /* fallback for old browsers */
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(to right, #f64f59, #c471ed, #12c2e9);  /* Chrome 10-25, Safari 5.1-6 */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #f64f59, #c471ed, #12c2e9); /* W3C, IE 10+/ Edge, Firefox 16+, Chrome 26+, Opera 12+, Safari 7+ */
  
}

body, html, .App, #root, .outer {
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}

.navbar-light {
  background-color: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgba(34, 35, 58, 0.2);
}

.outer {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  text-align: left;

}

.inner {
  width: 800px;
  margin: auto;
  background: #ffffff;
  box-shadow: 0px 14px 80px rgba(34, 35, 58, 0.2);
  padding: 40px 55px 45px 55px;
  border-radius: 15px;
  transition: all .3s;

}

.outer .form-control:focus {
  border-color: #167bff;
  box-shadow: none;
}

.outer h3 {
  text-align: center;
  margin: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

.custom-control-label {
  font-weight: 400;
}

.forgot-password,
.forgot-password a {
  text-align: right;
  font-size: 13px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  color: #7f7d7d;
  margin: 0;
}

.forgot-password a {
  color: #167bff;
}
```

Comment: You didn't forget to set the font-size in the body. Is that not your problem? :)

Comment: on the body, it has no effect but on the .inner tag, it helps a bit but still doesn't give me the result I want.

Comment: The size of the elements also depends on the settings in the system. I don't know about IOS, but in windows you can set it to scale the whole system, including the fonts. Then the browser also enlarges everything because it takes the basic settings from the system.

Comment: Yeah i figured this is what it is doing but now i gotta set the font to 0.6rem to look ok but the fonts are too small now. Any idea how to prevent the browser from scalling the elements along with the fonts?

Comment: Look at this [responsive-font-calculator](https://websemantics.uk/tools/responsive-font-calculator/) and this [clamp()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/clamp())